# how to calculate the range of a projectile from a height?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

**Player Projectile Diagram**

[image: Player Projectile Diagram]

What I am trying to do is having the player launched off from a point with known velocity, height from ground, angle and gravity.
and I am trying to find is what the distance the player will cross until he reaches the ground again.

I have attempted to calculate it with the following formula, but it doesn't seem to give me the correct result:

```
public static float Range(float velocity, Vector3 direction, float angle, float gravity, float heightFromGround)
{
    float xVelocity = velocity * direction.x;
    float yVelocity = velocity * direction.y;

    //R = Vx * [Vy + √(Vy² + 2 * g * h)] / g
    float result = (xVelocity * (yVelocity + Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(yVelocity, 2) + 2 * Mathf.Abs(gravity) * heightFromGround) / Mathf.Abs(gravity)));
    return result;
}
```

**More details:**

what I am doing is I have an infinite level that spawns platforms and hooks.

what I want is that after the last spawned hook, the platform will be placed exactly at where the player will reach at position.y = 0

this is how I am trying to achieve that:

```
private void HookSpawnerFinished(TrackPart lastHook)
{
    hookSpawnerActive = false;
    Vector3 lastHookGroundPosition = new Vector3(lastHook.transform.position.x, 0);
    float hookRangeToGround = HookRangeToGround(lastHook);
    Vector3 platformPosition = new Vector3(lastHook.transform.position.x + hookRangeToGround, 0);
    ActivatePlatformSpawner(platformPosition);
}

private float HookRangeToGround(TrackPart lastHook)
{
    print($"last hook Y position: {lastHook.transform.position.y}");
    float DistanceToGround = PhysicsHelper.ProjectileMotion.Range(hookAbilityParameters.MaxHookForce, MathHelper.DegreeToVector2(hookAbilityParameters.MinExitAngle), hookAbilityParameters.MinExitAngle, hookAbilityParameters.Gravity, lastHook.transform.position.y);
    return DistanceToGround;
}
```

the `DistanceToGround` value is way too big and places the platform way further from however much the player is even going to reach.

[image]

I have used this [trajectory predictor](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/physics/trajectory-predictor-55752) asset from the asset store,
and it's giving me the correct projectile motion arc, but I haven't found a way to figure out how to calculate the range from the code of the asset.

[image]

but as you can see, the platform that I want to spawn is nowhere near that. So all in all, both of the player and the trajectory predictor's maths are "matched" but the function I have to calculate the range is not.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output you expect and what you are getting

Comment: @Jawad edited as requested, I hope the given information is sufficient

Comment: thank you for the details.. it helped figuring out the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the formula you have is supposed to the gravity divided by the square root + velocity of y.

Try this

```
    float result = xVelocity * (yVelocity + Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(yVelocity, 2) + 2 * Mathf.Abs(gravity) * heightFromGround)) / Mathf.Abs(gravity);
```

You are doing

```
    //R = Vx * [Vy + √(Vy² + 2 * g * h) / g]
```

instead of

```
    //R = Vx * [Vy + √(Vy² + 2 * g * h)] / g
```

Comment: oh! now I see the issue! works perfectly now. Thank you so much!